# Duvidas de consulta ao banco mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql, uwp

Existe como criar um código para verificar se existe um registro novo no banco de dados?

EX: foi inserido o id = 2, preciso criar um código que vai gerar uma notificação toda vez que surgir um novo id.

Comment: Uma maneira seria armazenar a ultima `id` e depois verificar se existe uma `id` maior.

Comment: Como faria isso?

Comment: "de meu código verificar se existe um novo dado" creio que isto precisa ser melhor explicado , mas asolução passa por trigger , event ou algo similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode criar uma trigger before insert, e na trigger fazer o que pretende! porque esta trigger vai ser acionada sempre que vai acontecer uma inserção

Answer (score 2):

Para quem não sabe o que é Trigger (que nem eu), o que você pode fazer é:

1} - Armazenar a quantidade de registros do banco de dados (select sum) que você verificou da última vez em um arquivo de texto. Ex:

`file_put_contents("quant.txt",$quant);`

2) - Na próxima verificação você pega o total de registros do banco de dados e compara com o valor do arquivo de texto. Ex:

```
SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

com

```
$content = file_get_contents('quant.txt');
```

3) - Se houve alteração crie algo para lhe avisar (janela flutuante, alerta ou sei lá o que vc pretende fazer nesse sentido) e atualize seu arquivo de texto

```
file_put_contents('quant.txt', $novaQuant);
```

"Verificar se há novos registros" não é fácil!! Não é suficiente apenas contá-los se eles suportam DELETEs. Ai é outra história.

Outra alternativa é toda vez que houver um insert ou delete o seu código disparar um mail pra sua caixa de correio eletrônico.